# How to call my integer from a method in a seperate class

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to call some integers into a class from a method within another class

```
public class Variables
{
    public void vary()
    {
        int DSpr
    }
}

public class BattleCalc
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Variables v = new Variables();
        v.vary();
        Scanner spr = new Scanner(System.in);
        DSpr = Integer.parseInt(spr.nextLine()); //This line here
    }
}
```

This is my code so far, but on DSpr = Integer.parseInt... eclipse gives me an error "DSpr cannot be resolved". Why is it not calling DSpr from Variables ?

Comment: did you try compiling and running this? You are trying to call a local variable of a method from a different class which is not possible

Comment: Not possible with the code

Comment: And you have two public classes in the same file?

Comment: Nothing is correct about this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" call some integers into a class from a method within another class" makes no sense to me. Variables in a method are local to that method ONLY

I think what you want to do is something like this

```
public class Variables
{
...
   public int DSpr;
}
...
v.DSpr = Integer.parseInt(spr.nextLine());
```

i.e Make DSpr a public member *variable* of the Variables class.

It is **recommended** that you instead make it a `private` variable and write setter-getter methods for users outside the class to use it.

Comment: How about making DSpr as private and setting it using it's setter method.?

Comment: @VallabhPatade yup that would be the recommended way. This was a basic answer to what the OP wanted

Answer (score 0):

Try this: in order to access a variable at another class, it must be declared as class variable.

At your Class Variables:

```
       public class Variables{
           int DSpr;

           public void vary(){
               //do assignment here or operation, if you want to create a method
               DSpr = 0;
           }
       }
```

Then call it on your main class.

Answer (score 0):

`int DSpr` is declared locally within `vary()` method and hence can't be accessed outside of that method. even in it's enclosing class `Variables`

To access a variable in another class, it should be defined as instance field. (or class variable / static variable)

```
public class Variables
{
    public int DSpr;
    // OR
    // public static int DSpr;
    public void vary()
    {

    }
}
```

Now, in `BattleCalc` class you can access as following:

```
Variables v = new Variables();
v.DSpr = Integer.parseInt(spr.nextLine());
// OR
// Variables.DSpr = Integer.parseInt(spr.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

here your `DSpr` variable scope is limited to this method only:

```
public void vary()
{
    int DSpr
}
```

so it can not be accessed anywhere else.

if you are using elsewhere you need to re-declare like:

```
int DSpr = Integer.parseInt(spr.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to assign a value to DSpr from altogether another class. You should declare DSpr as member variable in Variable class and assign it by calling setter in that class.

Your code will be like this.

```
 public class Variables
{
 private int DSpr;
 public void setDSPR(int DSpr)
 {
    this.DSpr=DSpr;
 }
```

}

```
public class BattleCalc
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Variables v = new Variables();
    Scanner spr = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        v.setDSPT(Integer.parseInt(spr.nextLine())); //This line here 
    } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.print("Invalid Input.!")
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Variables
{
    public void vary()
    {
        int DSpr; 
    }
}

public class BattleCalc
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Variables v = new Variables();
        v.vary();
        Scanner spr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int DSpr = Integer.parseInt(spr.nextLine()); //This line here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes You should get errors in above code, Here is my solution
I assume you want to change the variable value in vary(). But I am not sure the usage of this since you are not using the changed value in BattleCalc. 
So get and set the integer variable you can use getters and sertters but here I will do minimum modifications to your code to make it easy to understand (so I am not using getters and setters here although it is the ideal way of doing)

```
public class Variables {
    public int DSpr;

    public void vary() {
        // Change the value of DSpr
        DSpr = 10;
    }
 }

 public class BattleCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Variables v = new Variables();
            v.vary();
            Scanner spr = new Scanner(System.in);
            v.DSpr = Integer.parseInt(spr.nextLine()); //This line here
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for comparison, this is a better answer than your other three. Please do more answers like this, where you explain and post code, rather than links.